# Ordering interaction levels using fct_relevel

Tags: r

I have a 2 by 2 design with a reference level for genotype (`gen = "WT"`) and treatment (`treat = "saline"`).
I am trying to reuse the code and not hardcode my levels (my `WT` will always be the reference level regardless of what other genotypes I'm using).
Here's a toy example of my dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)
toy1 <- tidyr::expand_grid(
  gen = c("WT", "QQ"),
  treat = c("saline", "ab")
)

toy1 %>% 
  mutate(gen = fct_relevel(gen, reference="WT"),
         treat = fct_relevel(treat, reference="saline"),
         inter = interaction(gen, treat)) %>% 
  pull(inter)
```

Which gives me

```
[1] WT.saline WT.ab     QQ.saline QQ.ab    
Levels: WT.saline QQ.saline WT.ab QQ.ab
```

This is close, but **my desired output** would be

```
[1] WT.saline WT.ab     QQ.saline QQ.ab    
Levels: WT.saline WT.ab QQ.saline QQ.ab
```

In this case, the order of the `tibble` and the levels is the same, but this cannot be taken for granted, and the `levels(inter)` is what matter to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `lex.order` to be `TRUE` in `interaction`

```
toy1 %>% 
  mutate(gen = fct_relevel(gen, reference="WT"),
         treat = fct_relevel(treat, reference="saline"),
         inter = interaction(gen, treat, lex.order = TRUE)) %>% 
  pull(inter)
```

-output

```
[1] WT.saline WT.ab     QQ.saline QQ.ab    
Levels: WT.saline WT.ab QQ.saline QQ.ab
```

---

Or we may add a `factor` at the end with `levels` specified as `unique` values

```
toy1 %>% 
  mutate(gen = fct_relevel(gen, reference="WT"),
         treat = fct_relevel(treat, reference="saline"), 
          inter = interaction(gen, treat), 
          inter = factor(inter, levels = unique(inter))) %>% 
  pull(inter)
```

-output

```
[1] WT.saline WT.ab     QQ.saline QQ.ab    
Levels: WT.saline WT.ab QQ.saline QQ.ab
```

Comment: I'm curious, `lex.order` is not following lexical order here, how is it that this works ? Same idea with `unique(inter)`...if this is relying in any lexical order or data order I would prefer not to use it.

Comment: @MatiasAndina wouldn't this be better if you create and example that wouldn't arrive at the expected output from other methods

Comment: I think your code works, I can't break it...I'm just trying to understand how come `lex.order` is not actually following a lexical order. The internals of it are unclear to me, I never would have guessed this was going to do the trick.

Comment: the documentation is kind of vague as well `By default, when lex.order = FALSE, the levels are ordered so the level of the first factor varies fastest, then the second and so on. This is the reverse of lexicographic ordering (which you can get by lex.order = TRUE), and differs from :. `

Comment: Yeah...docs was not doing it for me...you still solved my issue so much appreciated! If I somehow make it explode in the future I will come back and post the example